# Indirect reference to a object member is powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an object :

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path ("Registry:"+$my_registry_key) -Name $my_entry
```

But I still have several useless properties.  I would like to compare wath is expected to get out (a string)  to zero.

Since % operator is maybe a bit too magical...  I would like to expend it to make an indirect reference to property instead of a direct (or hard-coded one).  What does happens if property does not exists?

```
( `
 ( Get-ItemProperty -Path ("Registry:$my_registry_key") `
 | need_some_magic -property $my_entry`
 ) -ne 0 `
)
```

And expect one boolean (either $false or $true).

Does Powershell have some kind of hash which can be retrieved through variable instead of $_.property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```powershell
Get-ItemProperty -Path ("Registry:"+$my_registry_key) | select -ExpandProperty $my_entry
```

So:

```powershell
if($(Get-ItemProperty -Path ("Registry:"+$my_registry_key) | select -ExpandProperty $my_entry) -ne 0) {
  ...
}
```